# Página de Erro 404 PADRÃO PHP HTACCES

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenha a seguinte estrutura no .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^www\/login\/?$ login/ [L,NC,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 www/errors/404.php
```

E a seguinte estrutura de pasta:

```
/public_html
  /www - Arquivos como index, editX, deleteX, updateX
    /errors - Dentro tem 404.php, 500.php, 403...
```

Eu quero que qualquer erro que der (404) seja em dentro de www, ou fora(na pasta de cima), tipo a pessoa digita:

1ª

> www.meusite.com.br/qualquercoisaqueeuseiquenãoexiste

ou

2ª

> www.meusite.com.br/www/outracoisaquenãoexiste

sejam redirecionados para errors/404.php, e a URL iria ficar semelhante a isso, SEMPRE:

> www.meusite.com.br/www/errors/404

Como eu poderia fazer isso, porque do jeito que tá nem na 1 nem na segunda tá redirecionando corretamente, está simplesmente mostrando um texto:

> www/errors/404.php

**EDIT**

Foi corrigido o erro de mostrar o texto ao invés de redirecionar, mas ele não está aplicando o estilo. No console é gerado esses erros:

```
GET https://www.meusite.com.br/www/wjhbdsbn 404 (Not Found)
GET https://www.meusite.com.br/assets/css/error.min.css 
GET https://www.meusite.com.br/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Minha página 404.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="https://www.meusite.com.br/" />
    <title>Metta Contabilidade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/error.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>404</h1>
        <p align="center">Página não encontrada!</p>
        <p align="center">Indica uma dificuldade em encontrar uma página (arquivo ou diretório) especificada na barra de endereço.</p>
    </div><br>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="javascript:history.back()">
           <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar
        </a><br><br>

        <a href="../main.php">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar para página inicial      
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar uma `/` antes de `www/errors/404.php`. Na [documentação](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) diz: "*A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/")*".

Comment: Okay isso funcionou. Mas meu estilo não está aparecendo, está mostrando somente o texto. Ele redireciona mas só mostra o texto.Poderia me ajudar a encontrar o porque? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Coloque a URL absoluta para os arquivos CSS, não a relativa.

Comment: Não seria isso que o <base href="meusite.com.br"> faz? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Tira os `..` dos CSS, caso o diretório esteja na raiz do projeto...

Comment: Não está na raiz. @KaduAmaral

Comment: Desta forma ele estaria acessando os arquivos CSS fora do diretório raiz, o que não faz sentido. Coloque algo como `/www/assets/...`, ou `/assets/...` se a pasta estiver na raiz do projeto.

Comment: Funcionou com a primeira opção: /www/assets/... Muito obrigado pela ajuda @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 7):

## Erro de redirecionamento

O erro de direcionamento ocorre devido a um erro no arquivo `.htaccess`. Conforme a [documentação](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html), a diretiva `ErrorDocument` tem o seguinte formato:

```
ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>
```

Onde o valor de `<action>` pode ser:

1. Uma URL local, se o valor iniciar com `/`;
2. Uma URL externa, se o valor for uma URL válida;
3. Texto a ser exibido, caso nenhuma das duas condições acimas sejam satisfeitas;

Como você colocou `www/errors/404.php` o Apache interpretará como texto. Para corrigir, basta adicionar uma barra no início, indicando que é uma URL local:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /www/errors/404.php
```

## Erro nos estilos

Os estilos CSS não são carregados pois o caminho definido está errado. Quando você utiliza:

```
<base href="https://www.meusite.com.br/" />
```

Junto com:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/error.min.css" />
```

O arquivo que tentará ser carregado estará fora do diretório raiz da aplicação e o acesso a este arquivo seria negado pelo Apache.

```
/var/.../public_html/../assets/css/error.min.css
```

Ou seja, fora do diretório `public_html`. Como a pasta `assets` está dentro do diretório `www`, que por sua vez se encontra no diretório raiz, basta você indicar o caminho absoluto para o arquivo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/www/assets/css/error.min.css" />
```